# Puppeteer and Axios receive a security token that... never works

Tags: javascript, axios, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape the movements of my bank account with Puppeteer, with a simple script that I run from VSCode. But the login always fails, even though the user and password are 100% correct.

After lots of HTTP requests testing, I found out the culprit is one cookie called `_abck` provided by the server when visiting the login url:
[image]

If I visit the website using Chrome and copy paste that cookie, the login requests work perfectly:
[image]

However, if I try to use the same token fresh from Puppeteer or Axios... it fails with a 403:
[image]

I have even tried this: running the code and when Chromium appears, I open a new tab, go to my bank's website, get the cookie from devtools, paste it in a request and fails the same way. I'm puzzled.

Why? How can I get a working `_abck` token programmatically?

Comment: The technology you are fighting is [Akamai Bot Manager](https://www.akamai.com/products/bot-manager)

Comment: It may be easier to use an API provider based on PSD2 to connect to your bank, such as [Nordigen](https://nordigen.com/en/banks/open-banking/bbva/), instead of fighting bot protection.